# Net CDF data for humidity

Tags: climate, humidity, netcdf

Hello I am looking for a NetCDF data set that shows the change in humidity since about 1850. I have found this one for precipitation: https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/cmap/enh/ but cannot find one for humidity change